# How does one integrate a function of the form: $\int \frac{x}{(a+x)^2}dx$

Tags: integration

How does one integrate a function of the form:

$$\int \frac{x}{(a+x)^2}dx$$

I've considered subbing in for $u$, inverse trig methods, and integrating by parts but I haven't found a solution.

Comment: $u = x + a \implies \int \frac {u-a}{u^2} du \implies \int \frac 1u -\frac a{u^2} du $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\int  \frac { x }{ (a+x)^{ 2 } } dx&=\int  \frac { x+a-a }{ (a+x)^{ 2 } } dx\\&=\int  \frac { d\left( a+x \right)  }{ (a+x) } -a\int { \frac { d\left( a+x \right)  }{ (a+x)^{ 2 } }  }\\&=\ln { \left| a+x \right| +\frac { a }{ a+x }  } +C
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: That's beautiful , thank you sir.

Comment: you are welcome)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use partial fractions:

If $\displaystyle\frac{x}{(a+x)^2}=\frac{A}{a+x}+\frac{B}{(a+x)^2}$, multiplying by $(a+x)^2$ gives $\;x=A(a+x)+B$, and then

equating the coefficients of $x$ gives $A=1$, and letting $x=-a$ gives $B=-a$.

(This is the standard way to get this, but the previous answer gives a nice way to get the same form.)

Now you can find $\displaystyle\int\left(\frac{1}{a+x}-\frac{a}{(a+x)^2}\right)dx$.

---

Alternatively, using integration by parts with $u=x, du=dx$ and $\displaystyle dv=\frac{1}{(a+x)^2}, v=-\frac{1}{a+x}$

gives $\displaystyle -\frac{x}{a+x}-\int-\frac{1}{a+x}dx=-\frac{x}{a+x}+\ln|a+x|+C$

---

As pointed out in the comments, the substitution $u=x+a$, so $x=u-a$ and $du=dx$,

is also a good way to find this integral.